# How to parse Facebook fan page from HTML code with PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all, facebook-page

I need **regex pattern** example for PHP with **preg_match_all** usage how to parse **Facebook fan page** URL from the HTML code.

Examples:

```
http://www.facebook.com/pages/SomeTitle/6203451642
http://www.facebook.com/SomeTitle
```

Comment: You know, in case of `http://www.facebook.com/SomeTitle` "SomeTitle" can be name of the user, unless you query the Graph API you never know that's a page...

Answer (score 0):

```
/((?:https?:\/\/(?:\w+\.)?)?facebook\.\w+\/[^\s">'\};]+)/
```

The above captures the urls in group 1.

That should work for facebook in all regions (top-level domains) and for HTTPS or HTTP or users omitting that altogether and just writing facebook.com/mypage.